# Audio loudness metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming, fmp4

Apple's HLS stream validator gives me this warning:

```
Audio loudness information SHOULD be provided
```

I want to write a test that checks loudness information is present.  I cannot find what metadata keys are used to provide this information so that I can inspect them.

How would I determine if loudness normalization information is provided with a particular mp4 file using ffprobe or ffmpeg?

Comment: Do you have a file with loudness info?